# Using neo4j find the current user unrelated nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a trouble when fetch the unrelated nodes. pls refer the image [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vq3sq.png). as per the image "Mother of john" is the current user. i want to find which nodes all are unrelated for "Mother of john"
(Eg: "Father of Mohanraj" , etc.)

here is my query

```
match (m:member) where id(m) = 36 
with m 
match (p:member)-[*]-() 
with collect(p) as parents 
match (w:wedding)<-[:WED_TO]-(i) 
where not i in parents 
return i
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, m is not used to filter the results of the second part.
I would go along the lines below:

```
// return the user
MATCH (m:member) where id(m) = 36 
WITH m
// return all members that are not related to m
MATCH (p:member)
WHERE NOT (p)-[:WED_TO|PARENT_FROM*]-(m)
RETURN p
```